# How do I fix an aspect ratio in ggplot2's geom_hex?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to use `geom_hex` to represent my counts, but I want the hexagons to be "square", with an aspect ratio 1:1.

I've seen `coord_fixed` (and its alias `coord_equal`), but these change the aspect ratio of the whole plotted area, while I'm interested in changing the aspect ratio of the hexagons themselves.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Here, in plot1.pdf, the hexagon aspect ratio is determined by 
# the saved plot aspect ratio
plt1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_hex(bins = 10)
ggsave("plot1.pdf", plt1, width = 5, height = 4)


# Here, in plot2.pdf, the hexagon aspect ratio is 1:1, but the
# plot doesn't fill the space well, particularly if the data change
ratio <- 2
plt2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_hex(bins = 10 * c(1, ratio)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = ratio)
ggsave("plot2.pdf", plt2, width = 5, height = 4)


# In plot3.pdf, the only thing that's changed is the y-axis data,
# but the plot is unreadable because the x-axis is so compressed
ratio <- 2
plt3 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = 5 * Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_hex(bins = 10 * c(1, ratio)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = ratio)
ggsave("plot3.pdf", plt3, width = 5, height = 4)
```

In `plot2.pdf` and `plot3.pdf` above, the hexagons have a 1:1 aspect ratio, but the plots don't look good, because `coord_fixed` has scaled the entire plotted area, not just the hexagons.

In each plot, I could tweak the `bins` argument to get hexagons with an aspect ratio near 1:1, but I'd like to have the code pick automatically for me. Is there a way to say something like "pick 15 bins on the x-axis and however many bins are necessary on the y-axis to make the hexagons have a 1:1 aspect ratio"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to extract the size of the plotting area (in axis units) from the ggplot, then scale the hexagons (using `binwidth` rather than `bins` argument) based on the ratio.

```
plt1 = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_hex() 

xrange = diff(ggplot_build(plt1)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range)
yrange = diff(ggplot_build(plt1)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range)
ratio = xrange/yrange
xbins = 10
xwidth = xrange/xbins
ywidth = xwidth/ratio
plt1 = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_hex(binwidth = c(xwidth,ywidth)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = ratio)
ggsave("plot1.pdf", plt1, width = 5, height = 4)
```

[image]

Or, if you prefer the plotting area to have an aspect ratio the same as the page, rather than square, then you can adjust the ratio accordingly:

```
width = 5 
height = 4
ratio = (xrange/yrange) * (height/width)

xwidth = xrange/xbins
ywidth = xwidth/ratio
plt1 = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_hex(binwidth = c(xwidth,ywidth)) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = ratio)

ggsave("plot1.pdf", plt1, width = width, height = height)
```

[image]